# contenteditable on JQueryMobile Lists

Tags: jquery-mobile, editor, wysiwyg, contenteditable, html-editor

I am trying to design a WYSIWYG editor for JQueryMobile pages using `contenteditable`.

But I cannot get the caret to focus on the `<a>` tags inside `ListView` items and `<a>` tags styled with `data-role=button`.

Instead the caret always focuses into the `<span>` used for showing the arrow icon.

How do I allow the user to modify the Link text and the Link hyperlink?

Here's [a JSFiddle with code](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/NtBws/) I am trying to work with.